# django-paypal tutorial: 'reverse' seems to be used incorrectly

Tags: python, django, paypal

I am attempting to use django-paypal (perhaps there is a better library?) and I'm learning from this page here: https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html

In this block `reverse` is used but it throws an error when employed in a project (even if you import it)

```
paypal_dict = {
    "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
    "amount": "10000000.00",
    "item_name": "name of the item",
    "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
    "notify_url": "https://www.example.com" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),
    "return_url": "https://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
    "cancel_return": "https://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",

}
```

I'm importing it like so:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

And I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /pay/

Reverse for 'paypal-ipn' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Either I missed something or the tutorial is incomplete (or wrong?); I just need some correction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't add this in my urls:

```
url(r'^something/paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
```